# How to animate arrow

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to make an arrow go up with an animation but can't seem to make it work.
The margin-top starts on 180px.
This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $('#pijl').animate({
        $(this).css('margin-top', '120px');
    },500);
},6000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set your arrow in css like this position: relative.
now in your jquery code try this one.
the callBack function will animate the arrow in infinite loop..than using setInterval.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function animated() {
    $('div.animated-arrow').animate({top: '50px'},500).animate({top: '120px'},500,animated);
}

animated();
```

});

wish it will help you.